# How to use CheckConstraint count on a Many-to-Many relationship?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a basic `Person` table. Each person can have at most 5 friends. I want enforce that check with a database-level constraint.

I have tried using `func.count` as described here (http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#counting) but with no success, getting this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) misuse of aggregate function count()
```

Here's my code:

```
friend_table = Table(
    'friend', Base.metadata,
    Column('left_id', Integer, ForeignKey('person.id')),
    Column('right_id', Integer, ForeignKey('person.id'))
)


class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'person'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    friends = relationship('Person',
                           secondary=friend_table,
                           primaryjoin=friend_table.c.left_id == id,
                           secondaryjoin=friend_table.c.right_id == id)

    __table_args__ = (
        CheckConstraint(func.count(friends) < 5, name='max_friends_constraint'),
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering this old question as I couldn't find any other satisfactory answers. Based on my investigation this `CheckConstraint` is not impossible using JOIN queries, but it is nonetheless very inefficient.

However, an `event` can be used instead, checking on the number when `append` occurs in order to enforce a max number of friends. The code sample below should match your intended case:

```
from sqlalchemy import event
from sqlalchemy.exc import IntegrityError

@event.listens_for(Person.friends, "append")
def receive_append(target, value, initiator):
    if len(target.friends) >= 5:
        # Raising this exc just as an example, just adapt to your needs
        raise IntegrityError("person.friends.append", None, None)

    # This returns the value, hence the friend will be appended normally
    return value
```

This should be a good solution if you're only going to use sqlalchemy. If you plan to use raw queries to interact with your Db in any other form, then you'll likely need an additional `trigger` for your association table `friend` to enforce your rule.